# How to simplify code?

Tags: function, xcode4

I'm building an very simple application and I would like to reduce the coding lines in it, and I would like to that by using one or two functions instead of 20.

The app displays 10 buttons. Each button has two buttons to display, both with the same action (sending an email) but each button has a different identity so it also has different email content. It works fine if I do a function for each button, but I know it's possible to simplify that, I just don't know how.

Can someone point me in the right direction? This is what I'm doing right now in my methods:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *controller1 = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

controller1.mailComposeDelegate = self;
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    [controller1 setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"dev@company.com", nil]];
    [controller1 setSubject:@"Button 1"];
    [controller1 setMessageBody:@"The second option form button 1 was selected" isHTML:NO]; 
    [self presentModalViewController:controller1 animated:YES];

}
    [controller1 release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a unique tag (see the tag property) for each button and check the tag of the sender in your one -sendEmail: method. All your buttons call that one method.

Comment: thanks for the response! but where should I declare the tags? I did this but didn't work: 

        St01e01 = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:101];
 Vt01e01 = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:102];

        if (101) {
   [controller1 setMessageBody:@"Button 1 option 1" isHTML:NO]; 
  }else if (102) {
   [controller1 setMessageBody:@"Button 1 option 2" isHTML:NO];

Comment: You SET a button's tag. myButton.tag = 101 (or, in your case, set it in Interface Builder) ... then read the SENDER'S tag: if (sender.tag == 101) in your method

Comment: does it need a framework or something? because it marks error: "Request for member 'tag' in something not a structure or union"

Comment: oops, nevermind, the method declaration was wrong, I wrote (id) sender instead of (UIButton *)sender... thanks!!

Comment: Post your code (in your original question, not in comments or as an answer).